# How to calculate total hours worked after a fixed time?

Tags: excel

I'm having trouble creating a basic algorithm that does the following:

1. Calculate total hours worked after a certain time, for example 5:00PM

Is there a built-in algorithm to find the difference in the text timestamp AFTER a fixed time?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
=TEXT(MAX(0,SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C2,"PM"," PM"),"AM"," AM")-TIME(17,0,0)),"[HH]:mm")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, could you breakdown the parts of this algorithm

Comment: First we need to change the string to a format that Excel can interpolate as a time.  That is what the two nested Substitutes do.  Then we subtract 5 pm which is Time(17,0,0).  Then we return the max of that or 0 so we return 0 if the time is not in excess of 5pm.  Then we format it as hh:mm on the return.